# How to withdraw money from AdMob

Tags: android, admob

this is my first month in AdMob and I have a pending earning of $51, I thought to withdraw some of money from AdMob to my Bank account, but when I click in Transfer Funds it prompts that funds will be transferred to my Advertisement account, I don't want that, Is there any option for initiating funds transfer to my bank account?.

Also, I have not filled any Local Tax ID, will there be any problem? I am from India and have chosen ACH/Wire transfer option.

Comment: most promotion / advertising based services are scams and anyway this is a programming site.

Comment: But AdMobs? Its a service by Google.

Comment: You don't withdraw money from Admob. They pay you with a 2/3 month delay.

Comment: @SpliFF, i want to know that is it compulsory to have "Local Tax Id"?